# array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, int given this error is showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want that a user have many products. there is some product which belongs to one user. but it showing array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, int given error. i think there is some problem in controller but i cant fixed it. someone help me. Thanks is advence
here is my ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreTagsRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 5) - 1) * 5);
    }

    function authapi(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User:: where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            return response([
                'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
            ],404);
        }

        $token = $user -> createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response,201);
    }

    function all_app_jsons(){
        return Product::all();
    }

    function search_by_name($name){
        return Product::where('name','like','%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }

    function search_by_id($id){
        return Product::where('id',$id)->get();
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$tag = Product::create($request->all());

        //return redirect()->route('admin.tags.index');
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:1024',
        ]);

        // $input = $request->all();
        $request->validated();
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }

        Product::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }else{
            unset($input['image']);
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }else{
            unset($input['logo']);
        }

        $product->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }

    // function indextwo(){
    //     //return DB::select("select * from  products");
    //    //DB::table('products')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
    //    return Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    // }

}
```

here is my Product.php as model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo','user_id'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

here is my user.php as model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

here is my product table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }
```

Comment: where is array_map() in your code?

Comment: i don't know . where it should be can you help me. i am stragling with its with last 4 hours

Comment: What is the error stack trace? The error is that you're passing a non array when it is expecting an array. Your error reporting should tell you which line from ProductController is doing that. Which line?

Comment: its not showing any error in my ProductController but it showing error in ValidationRuleParser.php line 92

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this piece of code from your `ProductController`:

```php
            'user_ID' => auth()->user()->id,
```

It errors because instead of a validation rule you have the actual user ID there.

I'm assuming you wanted the user ID to be the current user ID and wanted to validate that, you can but not like this.

If you want to be sure the `user_id` from your input is always the authenticated user ID use this:

```php
$input = $request->all();
$input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
```

The error is because the user ID is probably an integer value, if we look at the code where the error occurred [`ValidationRuleParser:92`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43518afa5253600513b19ba7c3d4aad2a3eb69c3/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationRuleParser.php#L84-L93) you can see it checks for a string and object and otherwise passes the unmodified value to `array_map`, since you pass an integer it gives you the error you are seeing. Bit of a tricky one to figure out but the stack trace should have included a frame originating from your controller, specifically the `$request->validate` call.

---

Although technically not part of your question I want to warn about using `$request->all()` since this could potentially introduce extra data that is passed to your model without it being validated or intended. Instead use `$request->validated()` to get only the validated values. You also have `$fillable` set on your models, so it's not an immediate issue but I would still recommend only pass in validated fields just in case `$fillable` is expanded but the validation rules are not.

Comment: thanks you a lot its worked. but i can assess same product with different id`s. But i want a user id will have different products not assessable with different id. you can see i have update code with product table

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: That is an entirely different question right? The problem was in the store method which creates products and should have nothing to do with accessing them?

Comment: yes thanks you a lot i was straggling with this last 6 hours you helped me :) . But if you can't help me with other thats fine thank you :)

Comment: I can, but it's technically off-topic for this question... so I'll give it a quick go here but if it doesn't help create a new question. In your controller `update` method replace the `, Product $product` with `, $productId` and add as the first line of the method: `$product = auth()->user()->products()->findOrFail($productId);`. This should make sure only the products that belong the the authenticated user can be edited, alternatively check out: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping (but depending on your route setup this might not work for you).

Comment: Ok thanks for nice reply. but in this line ````$product = auth()->user()->products()->findOrFail($productId); ````it saying ````products()```` is undefined

Comment: Your post indicates the user model contains the products relation. So either the user is not authenticated or the user model you posted is incorrect. Best to open a new question since your original question has been answered.

Comment: If you can help over there:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653974/trying-to-store-and-edit-product-for-specific-user-id

Comment: I'll try, don't forget to mark this one as answered if it did so people reading know it's solved.