# Trying to store and edit product for specific user id

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Here I am trying to store and edit the product for a specific id. Wher a user can have some product and those products can be edit for this specific user. I have tried to do this but don't know what`s the problem is happening. can someone help me. Thanks in advance
this is my ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreTagsRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 5) - 1) * 5);
    }

    function authapi(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User:: where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            return response([
                'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
            ],404);
        }

        $token = $user -> createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response,201);
    }

    function all_app_jsons(){
        return Product::all();
    }

    function search_by_name($name){
        return Product::where('name','like','%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }

    function search_by_id($id){
        return Product::where('id',$id)->get();
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$tag = Product::create($request->all());

        //return redirect()->route('admin.tags.index');
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:1024',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        // $request->validated();
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }

        Product::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    // public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    public function update(Request $request, $productId)
    {
        $product = auth()->user()->products()->findOrFail($productId);
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }else{
            unset($input['image']);
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }else{
            unset($input['logo']);
        }

        $product->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }

    // function indextwo(){
    //     //return DB::select("select * from  products");
    //    //DB::table('products')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
    //    return Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    // }

}
```

in ProductController.php  `$product = auth()->user()->products()->findOrFail($productId);` in this line said `products()` id undefined
this is my model Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo','user_id'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is my User.php model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

This is product table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }
```

Note: I can store many products but not for specific users. I can store and edit product every user can access it. But I want a specific user will have some product where other user cant acess

Comment: why don't you use `Product::findOrFail($product_id)` or `auth()->user()->products()->where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->first()` ?

Comment: ````Product::findOrFail($product_id);```` This is running fine but not working still same resutl and ````auth()->user()->products()->where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->first();```` this is not working because undefined variable ````products()````

Comment: Do you have a user logged in ? If `auth()->user()->products()` -> `products()` is undefined, then `user()` is null... check that with a `dd`...

Comment: please show us the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: The problem is  Auth is fine but when I tried to show the registered product in list view for a specific user it is not working for the specific user its showing products for all user the same but if i registered for specific it working fine

Comment: i gass problem is there ```` public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
         return view('products.index',compact('products'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 5) - 1) * 5);}```` its showing all registerd products for all users not spacific user i want spacific user

Comment: Is the error you are getting `Call to a member function products() on null`? If this is so, the user is not authenticated, that needs to be solved first, then you can use the products relation on the authenticated user to make sure you only receive the products for that user, but that will never work unless the user is known in the first place so let's figure that out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
I userd This on projects table